# Connect two computers on different networks using socket python

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am trying to connect two computers in different networks using the socket library. On the first try I tried to connect two computers in the same network and it worked. Then I tried to connect my friend's computer with mine in different networks, making various attempts and various searches I could not connect the two computers, I disabled the firewalls of both the server (my computer) and the client (computer of the my friend), but nothing, they don't connect. Below the source code of the client and server. What did I do wrong?
Server-side source code:

```
import socket
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 9999

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((host,port))
sock.listen(1)
print(f"Server's ip: {host}\n Server's port: {port}")
print(f"Waiting for incoming connections...")
client, addr = sock.accept()
print(f"{addr} connected")
```

Client-side code:

```
import socket

host = "192.168.1.XXX"

port = 9999

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((host,port))
print("You are connected!")
```

After some time python gives this error:

```
TimeoutError: [Errno 119] Connection timed out
```

Comment: can you ping the other machine?

Comment: Tobin yes, i can.

Comment: From the client machine, with the server running can you telnet to port 9999 on the other machine?

Comment: barny, I was unable to telnet to the server in different network, but only succeeded when the client and server were in the same network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved the problem, I just had to open port 9999 from the router settings.